# Read particular cell value one by one from CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file and i want to read a particular cell value one by one. After that i am going to use that value in another function. I want to implement in Python.

Does anyone have any idea or someone has did same thing can share it?

Here is what I have tried so far

```
import csv 
from Imports import * 
u = uds (0x0, 0, 0x18DA43F1, 0, 0x18DAF143, 0) 
cr = csv.reader(open("ECUreset.csv", "r"),delimiter=';') 
included_cols = [1, 2] 
for row in cr: 
    #print row 
    content = list(row[i] for i in included_cols ) 
    print content 
    SendMessage (row[1], row[2], "DiagnosticSessionControl - programming session", True)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Please show some effort. :-)

Comment: I did but am not getting exact value of the cell,

Comment: Please show your code...

Comment: You have read about the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), I hope?

Comment: yes Tim  i have read about CSV module

Comment: OK, good. You should post your code in your question (you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18652508/edit) it), not in a comment where it's unreadable (as you can see).

Comment: Show some input (a row of the csv file), the output you get and the output you want instead.